# convert Christian calendar to shamsi

Tags: laravel, composer-php

i want convert date and time to persian calendar with this package :
https://github.com/hekmatinasser/verta/

this package convert to shamsi but in for loop doesnt work,

this code is run:

```
return new Verta($show[$i]['created_at']);
```

in this code show date and time to pesrian date time format

but this code doesnt work:

```
$ishow['message'][$i]['time'] =new Verta($show[$i]['created_at']);
```

in this code show with christian date time format.

my main problem is in for loop show 'created_at' with chiristian format

how can i use it?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: show created_at with christian format.

Comment: can I know your full code how you get variable `$show`

Comment: $show = comment::where([['type', 1]])->select('id', 'sender', 'receiver', 'text','created_at')->get();

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < count($show); $i++) {
$ishow['message'][$i]['time'] =new Verta($show[$i]['created_at']);
}

Comment: How are you using `$ishow` ?

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < count($show); $i++) { $ishow['message'][$i]['time'] =new Verta($show[$i]['created_at']); } 
return $ishow;

Comment: how you get `$ishow`, It seems your `$ishow` is not updated with your looping.

Comment: my code in running but 'created_at' not convert to persian calender

Comment: I tried using `foreach` or `for` loop is working, check my answer, I am curious how you initiate  `$ishow`

Answer (score 0):

I am interested to try the library so I tested it and it's worked with `New Verta($item->created_at)` or `Verta::instance($item->created_at)`. My code is like this:

```
foreach ($items as $item){
 $shamsi[] = Verta::instance($item->created_at);
}
dd($shamsi);
```

It seems your `$ishow` is not updated from the old form. let's try code below:

```
$ishow = [];
foreach ($show as $item){
 $ishow['message'][]['time'] = Verta::instance($item->created_at);
}
return $ishow;
```

or with for loop:

```
$ishow = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($show); $i++) { 
  $ishow['message'][$i]['time'] =new Verta($show[$i]['created_at']); 
}
return $ishow;
```

Comment: in this code format data is chiristian. i want show date and time in persian format

Comment: I tried and it's return persian,  I think something is wrong with your code, so please show your full code and the return of its